# Programming language tree

Tags: programming-languages

I'm feeling that I have many gaps in my programming, not the stuff I do but the stuff I know. I want to learn from beginning but there is no info on one page, at least I couldn't find it.
So, what I would like to know is which programming language is first who is its successor. I'm not interested in all languages just in line that leads to C++.

If someone is kind enough to write that with short info it would be great and would spare me of big headache.

**Little more:**

> I would like to understand how it was started and how it works, then advance to higher  level step by step in hope that
>   one day when I get knowledge about all of those I would be better
>   programmer. Thanks in advance and sorry to moderators if this Q/A site
>   is inadequate for this kind of question/request.

all  additional info for other languages is also welcome.

**Note**

```
> I don't want to lean how C++ started I want to know line that leads to
> C++ like 

> 1. Machine code
> 2. Assembly
> 3.... n.....  
> n+1. C++
```

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++.html
There are many papers and books linked off this page, all written by the inventor, many about its early development.

Comment: Refer to this: http://rigaux.org/language-study/diagram.html

Comment: Do you mean, "For each language, how was it implemented?", or do you mean, "For each language, what was its inspiration?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about the history of programming rather than programming itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Wikipedia's article ["Timeline of programming languages"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages):

```
Assembly --> Speedcoding --> FORTRAN --> ALGOL --> Simula --------------------+
                                               \                               \
                                                \                               \
                                                 +--> CPL --> BCPL --> B --> C --> C++
```